# Variadic template specialization, std::enable_if, SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, sfinae

A singleton class exposes this method for clients to obtain the instance:

```
template< typename ... Args >
static T & GetInstance( Args && ... args )
{
    if ( ! m_instance )
    {
        m_instance = new T( std::forward< Args >( args ) ... );
    }

    return * m_instance;
}
```

But for classes with no default constructors, it's annoying to allways pass the arguments. It would be better if, once the instance has already been created, to allow users just to call:

```
auto & instance = GetInstance( );
```

At first I thought that for this to work all it was needed was to specialize the templated method, say with:

```
// Wrong Version
template< >
static T & GetInstance< >( )
{
    if ( ! instance )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "Tried to get instance of non initialized singleton with no"
            " default constructor." );
    }

    return * instance;
}
```

But for classes with a default constructor, this specialization would be used *instead* of the more general one. I would like that such specialization be used *only if* `T` has no default constructor.

So I tried to change it a bit:

```
// Right Version
template< >
static auto GetInstance< >( ) ->
    typename std::enable_if<
        ! std::is_default_constructible< T >::value , T & >::type 
{
    if ( ! instance )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "Tried to get instance of non initialized singleton with no"
            " default constructor." );
    }

    return * instance;
}
```

So this worked, but I'm confused about the whole thing. To begin with, is the way I've done it the proper way to handle it? Shouldn't I being using `enable_if<>` as a parameter or a template parameter instead of a return type?

How the compiler works here? When it was just plain simple template specialization (in the *Wrong Version*) I guess the compiler realized that the more specialized version was better for code calling `GetInstance()` with no parameters (`T` being a class with a default construtor).

For the version with the `enable_if<>`, the compiler begins thinking that it would be better also to use the more specialized version, but then the code was ill formed. So it falls back to the general version? Is this also called SFINAE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handy rule of thumb: don't specialize, overload.

```
template <class... Args>
static T& GetInstance(Args&&... );

template <class U=T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_default_constructible<U>::value, int> = 0>
static T& GetInstance();
```

If `T` is default constructible, you only have one viable overload. If it's not, the second is more specialized when `Args` is empty and is preferred.

---

Note. This design seems suspect.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! It really seems clearer with the overload. But why do you use `class U=T` and then use `U`? Does this have to do with the overload resolution?

Comment: @Tarc SFINAE only applies in the immediate context. If you did `is_default_constructible<T>::value`, where `T` is not a template parameter, that would immediately evaluate and you would get a hard error.